# add attribute with colon to xml node in php

Tags: php, html, xml, web, attributes

I have an xml value in the php variable and i need to add the attribute `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim http://www.loc.gov/standards/marcxml/schema/MARC21slim.xsd"
    and xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim"` on the 'record' element . Below is my xml in php

```html
<record xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
  <leader>01344cam a2200385 i 4500</leader>
  <controlfield tag="001">19196211</controlfield>
  <controlfield tag="005">20160810165833.0</controlfield>
  <controlfield tag="008">160728t20162015nyu           000 1 eng  </controlfield>
  <datafield tag="906" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
    <subfield code="a">7</subfield>
    <subfield code="b">cbc</subfield>
    <subfield code="c">orignew</subfield>
    <subfield code="d">2</subfield>
    <subfield code="e">ncip</subfield>
    <subfield code="f">20</subfield>
    <subfield code="g">y-gencatlg</subfield>
  </datafield>
</record>
```

Other characters are working in the place of colon , but colon is not working . I know it's got something related to namespaces but i cant figure out the problem . Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When adding an attribute with a :, this is as you say adding an attribute with a namespace.  What you need to do is ensure that this namespace is defined.  So when adding the attribute, you use the third parameter as the URI for the namespace...

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//zs:record//def:record')[0];
$nodes[0]->addAttribute('xsi:schemaLocation', 'http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim',
        'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');

echo $nodes[0]->asXML();
```

gives...

```
<record xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
```

Comment: so i wrote this . `$nodes[0]->addAttribute('xsi:schemaLocation', 'http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim http://www.loc.gov/standards/marcxml/schema/MARC21slim.xsd',
        'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');

$nodes[0]->addAttribute('xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
`

Comment: And the output is `<record xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim http://www.loc.gov/standards/marcxml/schema/MARC21slim.xsd" xsi:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">`   Note that `xsi:xsi` is unnecessary and it should not come.

Comment: and yes i am trying to add two elements .. one is `xmlns:xsi` and the other is `xsi:schemaLocation`.

Comment: You only need to add the one attribute, I've updated the code example to be clearer and added the output I get.

Answer (score 0):

Just add before name 'xmlns:' when the attribute name contains the colons:

> $object->addAttribute('xmlns:xsi:schemaLocation',
> 'http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim');